# How to get current time in the format 2009-12-24 14:20:57 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm not familiar with time operations in javascript.

I tried `new Date();` which gives the result in wrong format:

> Thu Dec 24 2009 14:24:06 GMT+0800

How to get the time in format of `2009-12-24 14:20:57`？

Comment: Do you want to also pad the fields less than 10? A better example will be with some values less than 10.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no cross browser Date.format() method currently.  Some toolkits like Ext have one but not all (I'm pretty sure jQuery does not).  If you need flexibility, you can find several such methods available on the web.  If you expect to always use the same format then:

```
var now = new Date();
var pretty = [
  now.getFullYear(),
  '-',
  now.getMonth() + 1,
  '-',
  now.getDate(),
  ' ',
  now.getHours(),
  ':',
  now.getMinutes(),
  ':',
  now.getSeconds()
].join('');
```

Comment: Think carefully about whether you want this in local time or with a time zone (or "Z"), also padding is needed.  ES5 provides a toISOString() method, available in some browsers today.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function formatDate(d){
   function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
   return [d.getUTCFullYear(),'-',
          pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1),'-',
          pad(d.getUTCDate()),' ',
          pad(d.getUTCHours()),':',
          pad(d.getUTCMinutes()),':',
          pad(d.getUTCSeconds())].join("");
  }

  var d = new Date();
  var formattedDate = formatDate(d); 
</script
```

Answer (score 2):

to format date

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
curr_month++;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
document.write(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
//-->
</script>
```

prints : **24-12-2009**

to format time you can do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var d = new Date();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_min = d.getMinutes();

var curr_sec = d.getSeconds();

document.write(curr_hour + ":" + curr_min + ":" 
+ curr_sec);

//-->
</script>
```

prints : **8:32:33**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice on

[JavaScript (ActionScript) Date.format](http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format)

or you can use like this

```
var dt = new Date();

var timeString = dt.getFullYear() +  "-" + dt.getMonth() + "-" + dt.getDate() + " " + dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() +":" + dt.getSeconds()
```

Answer (score 1):

> to format time you can do
>
> prints : 8:32:33
>
> Share Edit Follow edited Dec 24 '09 at 6:29 answered Dec 24 '09 at
> 6:24
>
> EzzDev
>
> thx EzzDev <33333 in my case:

```html
<input type="time" id="appt">
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="gettimenow()">
<script>
function gettimenow(){
       
            var d = new Date();
        var curr_hour = d.getHours()<10? '0'+d.getHours():d.getHours();
        var curr_min = d.getMinutes()<10? '0'+d.getMinutes():d.getMinutes();
            var time24 =  curr_hour + ":" + curr_min;
        document.getElementById('appt').value = time24;
        console.log(time24);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: fix code formatting

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30281735)

Answer (score 0):

Use the pieces of the date as found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), to format to your liking.

ie.

```
var now = new Date();
var formatStr = now.getFullYear() + " - " + now.getMonth() + " - " + now.getDate();
// formatStr = "2009 - 12 - 23"
```

Answer (score 0):

My JavaScript implementation of Java's SimpleDateFormat's format method may help you: http://www.timdown.co.uk/code/simpledateformat.php